# how to sign a PSBT with bitcoinjs-lib in node js?

Tags: node.js, blockchain, bitcoin, bitcoinjs-lib

I am trying to sign a PSBT that is generated by magicEden (NFT marketplace) so I can purchase ordinals NFT from it using code,

am using node js, and I was able to debug the site to find how they generate the PSBT by using this Code.

```
import { Psbt } from 'bitcoinjs-lib'
const PsbtInstance = new Psbt();
// unsignedBase64 is the site endpoint response 
const psbt = Psbt.fromBase64(unsignedBase64);
```

but what I am failing to locate is how they sign this **PSBT** so they can initiate the Transaction since as I was debugging the site I noticed that they send the **PSBT** to UNISAT extension which will sign the PSBT and return it

any help is appreciated,

Quick notice am not trying to do any malicious or unethical automation on magiceden , all of this is just for sake of learning